# Almost the same code, but different output, why?

Tags: php, utf-8, fgetc

I'm working with UTF-8 encoded text files,and cant find proper solution...

after I couldn't solve a problem with string, I'm trying fgetc() now, but it also doesn't work.
This code:

```
$file = fopen("t1.txt","r+");
while (! feof ($file))
{
  $c= fgetc($file);
  echo $c;
  //echo "\t";
}
fclose($file);
```

works fine, and outputs: **abcd абвқ efg**
but if I uncomment the //echo "\t", it doesn't work, it outputs: �  �   �   a   b   c   d    �  �   �   �   �   �   �   �    e  f   g

why? how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the file *byte* at a time.

For example the character `б` encodes as bytes `0xD0 0xB1` in UTF-8. The tab character is `0x09`.

So without the tab character, you first write `0xD0`, then `0xB1`, resulting in `0xD0 0xB1` which is valid UTF-8.

With the tab character, you write `0x09` between every byte - making it: `0xD0 0x09 0xB1`. `0xD0` followed by `0x09` is not
valid UTF-8, so the browser renders the replacement character to deal with it.

You need to be more sophisticated about it; this should work:

```
$file = fopen("t1.txt","r+");
while (! feof ($file))
{
  $c = fgetc($file);
  $val = ord($c);

  //UTF-8 Lead Byte
  if( $val & 0x80 ) {
    $continuationByteCount = 0;
    if( ($val & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $continuationByteCount = 3;
    else if( ($val & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $continuationByteCount = 2;
    else if( ($val & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $continuationByteCount = 1;

    echo $c;

    while( $continuationByteCount-- ) {
        echo fgetc($file);
    }

  }
  else { //Single-byte UTF-8 unit... I.E. ASCII
      echo $c;
  }
  echo "\t";
}

fclose($file);
```

Read it all at once and split to array where each item is 1 character (1-4 bytes):

```
$chars = preg_split( '//u', file_get_contents("t1.txt"), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );

foreach( $chars as $char ) {
    echo $char;
    echo "\t";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves this case, but is there anyway I could get the contents of file as UTF-8 at once, so that I won't need to deal with 0xF8 or whatever, couse there are a lot of thing to do for me with this file..
or anyway how could I properly get the contents of the file into string and access it by index?

Comment: @hurremdev see the alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a problem with the encoding recognition from the browser. You can try

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

Or set the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```